# Problem installing Ubuntu 10.10 on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, ubuntu

I keep getting an error when trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 on Windows 7. I insert the cd and then restart the computer. Everything looks like its loading great, but it gets stuck on the loading screen. So I pressed Esc, and it shows the following errors:

(process: 314): GLib-WARNING **: getpwuid_(r): failed due to unknown user id (0)

/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sdb: No medium found

I have also tried the check disc for defects options, but that also gets stuck on the loading screen. What am I missing? Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

sdb is not a CD/DVD but an HD.

Comment: Oh, ok. So am I suppose to install this from a hard drive?

Comment: No.  The point we are getting at is that you say you have an HD connected and a CD.  This sdb thing is a second HD.  Is it an HD? a thumbdrive?  update your question plz

Comment: That's strange. I only have one HD which is my internal c:/ drive where windows is installed. I don't have another HD.

Comment: it is odd, are you sure you don't have a second usb device of any kind connected?  sometimes weirdness ensues becuase (for compatibility) some devices expose their storage as an HD

Comment: I sometimes connect an external hd or thumbdrive, but they are not connected at the moment.

Comment: then check your /etc/fstab for entries relating to the external drives and comment them out if present (the lines beginning with a different uuid or /dev/sdbX add a # mark)

Comment: Ok, but how do I get to that file? Can I get to it when booting from cd? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, mount whatever partition houses /etc/.  This is situation dependent.  Sometimes it is in /dev/sda1, but there is no definitive answer

Comment: I am facing the same problem while installing Ubuntu 12.04, please help me if you have solved this issue ASAP. I am using live usb created with UnetBootin.